# Resize fancybox after initialization due to content change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, datatables

I'm working with jquery.datatables and as you may know, the datatable is initialized after the page is rendered, so that means that the height is set after, on runtime.
The issue here is that fancybox set the height dynamically depending on the page height, but because the height is changed afterwards it doesn't tke the good one.

here is how I set my fancybox popup:

```
    height: $(document).height(),
    width: $(document).width() > maxWidth ? maxWidth : $(document).width(),// Acts as max-width, not possible to set that through CSS.
    autoResize: true,
    closeBtn: false,
    type: 'iframe',
    wrapCSS: 'popup'// Custom class added to the fancybox div.
```

Autoresize is true, but it doesn't change anything in this case.

I'm looking for a solution here, in the meantime I set a min-height to the div but I don't really like it and it doesn't work properly.

Any trick or workaround?

Comment: You may need to run programmatically the method `$.fancybox.update()` after the content resize

Comment: I tried but it didn't have any effect :/

Comment: It looks like the problem is coming from something else, basically some CSS that set margin and padding with a total of 80px that creates the overflow and displays the scroller. I don't have a solution yet but it seems to no being connected to datatables nor to fancybox.